# Remove embedded quotes using regex

Tags: regex, quotes

How can I remove quotes around `"7"` only without removing quotes outside of it using Regex ?
Before:

```
|"Fairway "7" Townhouses"
```

After

```
|"Fairway 7 Townhouses"
```

Comment: is it only 7? or digits? is there any pattern?

Comment: If there is any outside quotes remove the inside quotes, it could be "Testing "inside" quotes" needs to change to "Testing inside quotes"

Comment: so.. your strings always start and end with quotes?

Answer (score 2):

The following will do a look-behind and a look-ahead to ignore the first and last instance of a quote while catching all those in between.

`(?<=".*)"(?=.*")`

Providing the dialect you are using supports look-ahead/behind such as in .NET.... (*javascript does not*)

Answer (score 0):

check this regex `(?<!^)"(?!$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cZ0wI0/3)

Comment: this regex catches `"` before and after `7` as stated in question `How can I remove quotes around "7"`

Comment: yeah I got your point , actually the question is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
(^"[^"]*)(?:"([^"]*)")?([^"]*?")
```

And replace with the following:

```
$1$2$3
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/3)

**General solution:** If you have strings embedded with multiple quoted strings, use the following and replace with `$1`:

```
(?<!^)"([^"]*)"(?!$)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cZ0wI0/2)

Answer (score 0):

See the Demo here which replaces all the "7" instances with 7. https://regex101.com/r/wP5bZ7/3

Comment: @karthikmanchala: I guess it will work. what is the issue with above eg. I have provided?